# React Native button click

Tags: button, react-native

Im an working on React Native application. I have two different screens, Login and Register. Both the components are present in different modules. But, when I add **onPress** prop to the button in one screen, it is affecting the other screen also. For ex, if I click button of login screen, it is calling function of register screen, even there is no such event added for login screen button.

Please look at the code blocks,

LoginForm.js

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainerRegister} onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate('RegisterScreen')}>
                        <Text  style={styles.buttonText}>REGISTER</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
```

RegisterForm.js

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainerRegister1}  testID="test1" >
                            <Text  style={styles.buttonText1} onPress = {Alert.alert("my")} >Register</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
```

When I click button of LoginForm.js, it is triggering event add for RegisterForm.js button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your RegisterForm.js, change this..

```
onPress = {Alert.alert("my")} //Self invoking
```

to this

```
onPress = {() => Alert.alert("my")} //Requires a Press event
```